# NSIS Installer (Unicode) writes in XML file instead of "<" "&lt;"

Tags: xml, unicode, installation, nsis

i have a little Problem with my NSIS script. I try to modify a connectionString in a config file.

I tried both compiler from NSIS (ANSII & Unicode) with the correct plugins.. in both cases in the XML file wasn't a "<" or ">" but two "& lt;" (without the space between & and l).

I use nsisXML as plugin.

Here my Code i tried it:

```
nsisXML::create
nsisXML::load "$INSTDIR\InvoiceConfigurator.exe.config"
nsisXML::select '/configuration/connectionStrings'
IntCmp $2 0 notFound
nsisXML::setText '<add name="InvoiceConfigurator.Properties.Settings.mdis_dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=$DataBaseInstance;Initial Catalog=$DataBaseName;User ID=$DataBaseUser;Password=$DataBasePw;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />'
nsisXML::save "$INSTDIR\InvoiceConfigurator.exe.config"
Goto end
notFound:
DetailPrint "InvoiceConfigurator.exe.config has not been adjusted!"
end:
```

The Message in DetailPrint is not shown !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly plugin homepage ( http://wiz0u.free.fr/prog/nsisXML/ ) this tool cannot insert subnodes as text like an JavaScript.
You should to insert each node and attributes manually. Something like this:

```
nsisXML::create
nsisXML::load "$INSTDIR\InvoiceConfigurator.exe.config"
nsisXML::select '/configuration/connectionStrings'
IntCmp $2 0 notFound
nsisXML::createElement "add"
nsisXML::setAttribute "name" "InvoiceConfigurator.Properties.Settings.mdis_dbConnectionString"
nsisXML::setAttribute "connectionString" "Data Source=$DataBaseInstance;Initial Catalog=$DataBaseName;User ID=$DataBaseUser;Password=$DataBasePw;"
nsisXML::setAttribute "providerName" "System.Data.SqlClient"
nsisXML::appendChild
nsisXML::save "$INSTDIR\InvoiceConfigurator.exe.config"
Goto end
notFound:
DetailPrint "InvoiceConfigurator.exe.config has not been adjusted!"
end:
```

Comment: Thank you Serge for your answer, i will try it soon !